# Is there a trick for word wrapping with non-monospaced fonts?

Tags: fonts, text-processing

I'm having a bit of trouble right now trying to implement word wrapping for non-monospaced fonts (The font can be different). I've tried searching for this everywhere but couldn't find a solution. Any tips?

Comment: please be more specific, what language / method are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

- store length in pixels of every word
- store pixel-offset of every word
- when text gets inserted in a line, update the offsets and, if necessary, break the line